# Why !(0 || 1 || 0) is 0?

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I am trying to understand Boolean logic and operators. 
I found this example but can't understand why this expression will evaluate to the one shown below.

Say, a = 0, b = 1, c = 0

```
           Expression           Will Evaluate to
val1 = !(a || b || c);        !(0 || 1 || 0) = !(1) = 0
```

As I see it, val1 is not `a` or not `b` or not `c`, so why it evaluates to not 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not(a or b or c) evaluates the or operations first, so it's not the same as  (not a) or (not b) or (not c).

Indeed, it's the same as (not a) AND (not b) AND (not c).

Either operand to an OR being true will give a true result, and then the NOT flips that to a false result for the expression as a whole.

As with integer or real number arithmetic, order of operation can greatly alter the result.

Answer (score 0):

> .... val1 is not a or not b or not c ...

No, this is incorrect. The `0 || 1 || 0` inside the parenthesis is evaluated first. The example has it right.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `val1 = 1` 
`1 = !(0 || 1 || 0)`
`1 = !(1)` - because it is the only value that is equal to val1
`1 = 0` - then it negates it afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Let's go step-by-step.

`val1 = !(0 || 1 || 0);`

Firstly, `0 || 1` will evaluate to 1, because `||` means 'true if at least one of them is true, otherwise false', and 1 = true, 0 = false.

So now it is
`val1 = !(1 || 0);` Here `1 || 0` will again evaluate to 1, because at least one of them is 1.  Now we've got `val1 = !(1);`. `!` means the opposite of the input, so `!(1)` = 0.

> As I see it, val1 is not a or not b or not c, so why it evaluates to not 1 ?

Because what you say would be written as `val1 = !0 || !1 || !0`. Its quite different, because it doesn't have parenthesis. Parenthesis means 'evaluate everything in the parenthesis first'.